# make list view show what I want JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx, observablelist

I have created a class and added it to a observable list, I also have a list view which I set its item to my observable list.

Problem is when I add an object from my class to the observable list, list view shows their address on memory like `package.TestClass@574f5892`, How can I make list view to show the text stored in each object and their image instead of their memory address?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick hack is just to define a `toString` method in your `TestClass` returning the text you want to display. This isn't really a robust solution, because in general you might want the `toString()` method to return something different from the text you want displayed in a GUI environment.

The "proper" way to do this is to set a `cellFactory` on the list view. Something along the lines of

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<TestClass>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(TestClass item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            String text = ... ; // get text from item
            setText(text);
        }
    }
});
```

To include an image, you can do

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<TestClass>() {

    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    @Override
    public void updateItem(TestClass item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            String text = ... ; // get text from item
            setText(text);
            Image image = ... ; // get image from item
            imageView.setImage(image);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In this mode can I add a radio button or something like that to it?

Comment: Sure. The `setGraphic(...)` method takes any `Node`. Can be an `ImageView`, `Shape`, `Control`, `Pane`, etc...

Comment: So then how can I change the order of them? For e.g I want to show radio button, text, image

Comment: Call `setText(null)`. Then put the radio button, a `Label` and the `ImageView` in an `HBox`, and set the graphic as the `HBox`... Or a `GridPane` if you want tighter control over the layout. Experiment with it for a while and if you are still stuck post a different question...

Comment: Perfect answer , just the time i needed it :) !